# Програма подсчета времени операций Collection

Tags: java, время, коллекции, операции

Есть 5 коллекций - `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, `TreeMap`, `HashMap`. На вход поступает `10000000` элементов с типом `Integer`.

Для колекций `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` посчитать скорость в милисекундах:

- добавление в начало;
- добавление в середину;
- добавление в конец;
- поиск по значению;
- удаление в начале;
- удаление в середине;
- удаление в конце.

Для коллекций `TreeMap`, `HashMap` посчитать скорость в милисекундах:

- добавление;
- поиск по ключу;
- удаление.

Данные воводятся один раз для всех колекций.

Как это все посчитать у одной коллекции понимаю, а как у всех 5 сразу нет?

Comment: Данные формируются один раз, а дальше крутите циклы для каждой коллекции отдельно с замером времени.

Comment: интересно, как вы в хешмэп в средину добавляете?))

Comment: Tree Map , HashMap:Посчитать скорость в милисекундах:
добавляя новое;
поиск по ключу;
удаление.

Comment: Есть специальные библиотеки и фреймворки для таких задач, например, JMH https://github.com/openjdk/jmh

Answer (score 0):

```
package t;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class CollecionOperaition {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> List = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            List.add(i);
        }
        List<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> copyOnWrite = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

        linkedList.addAll(List);
        arrayList.addAll(List);
        copyOnWrite.addAll(List);

        addBegin(linkedList);
        addBegin(arrayList);
        addBegin(copyOnWrite);
        System.out.println("addBegin");

        addMiddle(linkedList);
        addMiddle(arrayList);
        addMiddle(copyOnWrite);
        System.out.println("addMiddle");

        addEnd(linkedList);
        addEnd(arrayList);
        addEnd(copyOnWrite);
        System.out.println("addEnd");

        measureTime(linkedList);
        measureTime(arrayList);
        measureTime(copyOnWrite);
        System.out.println("measureTime");

        removeBegin(linkedList);
        removeBegin(arrayList);
        removeBegin(copyOnWrite);
        System.out.println("removeBegin");

        removeMiddle(linkedList);
        removeMiddle(arrayList);
        removeMiddle(copyOnWrite);
        System.out.println("removeMiddle");

        removeEnd(linkedList);
        removeEnd(arrayList);
        removeEnd(copyOnWrite);
        System.out.println("removeEnd");

        addEnd(linkedList);
        addEnd(arrayList);
        addEnd(copyOnWrite);
        System.out.println("addEnd");

    }

    private static void addBegin(List<Integer> list) {
        int j = 1;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.add(0, j);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - start);

    }

    private static void addMiddle(List<Integer> list) {
        int j = 1;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.add(list.size() / 2, j);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - start);
    }

    private static void addEnd(List<Integer> list) {
        int j = 1;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.add(j);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - start);
    }

    private static void measureTime(List<Integer> list) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            list.get(i);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - start);
    }

    private static void removeBegin(List<Integer> list) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.remove(0);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - start);
    }

    private static void removeMiddle(List<Integer> list) {
        int j = list.size() / 2;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.remove(j);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - start);
    }

    private static void removeEnd(List<Integer> list) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - start);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Подскажите как оптимизировать этот огромный код

Comment: Лучшая оптимизация, в данном случае удаление кода. Так измерять некорректно, нужно использовать специальные библиотеки вроде JMH